# jQuery Tracking Selection of Multiple DesignMode iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, contenteditable, designmode

I'm using `designMode="on"` on several iframes to allow user editing of their content. I also have buttons (outside the iframes) that, when clicked, should do something to the currently focused iframe. However, when you click the button, the button receives focus, meaning the iframes are all blurred--there's no focused iframe.

My question is, "how do I determine which of the several iframes was in focus just before the user clicked the button? I thought of tracking them by having each set a variable's value to iself when focused, but then if you click away from the boxes and then click the button, it won't know the difference (in that case, the button's function should do nothing, rather than using the last-focused box). So then I thought of setting that variable to null when the iframes are blurred, but of course, clicking the button blurs them and sets the variable to null >_< .

I've seen many places talk about finding the selected element within one designMode iframe, but nothing about finding the focused iframe out of several. How do I get this to work?

For the record, I'm using jQuery, but if there's a pure JS way of doing this, that's fine, too.